# Android wondering about how Child system work

Tags: android, listview

The question is : In a listview, are the children of the listView the elements visible on the screen ?

I mean I try everytime that the keyboard pop to trace the list children and to reach the last element of my list, but it's unreachable. Even if I go to the very bottom before tracing the children with `currentListView.setSelection(currentListView.getCount());`

I'm just looking for some explanations, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You call the last element with `currentListView.setSelection(currentListView.getCount()-1);` because indexing in the list starts with 0.

E.g. if your list has 3 elements they're numbered: 0|1|2. When you call `getCount()` you get 3, so it's out of bounds.

Comment: Well that's true but the auto-scrolling was working. So the problem remains. The thing I don't get is why when I do myList.getChild(index) on all indexes possible ( with getChildCOunt() ) I don't reach the ones a the very bottom of the listView.

Comment: How long is your list? I'm not sure, but I think that list items are recycled when they're not shown.

Comment: My list has non-constant size, but yes, it's recycled. But the thing is when I try to select the child I'm looking for which is totally visible thanks to the setSelection(), and ... well... this row is not in the list of child, even if it's visible.